# Italic and bold don't work

Tags: bug, formatting, markdown

[How to "italicize" a word in an italic paragraph?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/106106/26474)

That question doesn't italicize the words right from the edit panel, yet the bullets work. Why is that?

Test: *italic*, **bold**

[image]